# Python Pandas: Split Column & Unpivot with Varying Results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am running NLTK on a dataset and am looking to clean the end result by creating a single column containing the single words. A desired before/after view is shown below.

I figure that this would be a combination of splitting Tokenized and melting the dataframe. What is confusing me is how to handle differing counts of words for each comment. Any thoughts on what would solve this?

[image]

Comment: [Please dont post images in SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
df1 = df.explode("Tokenized")
df1.rename({"Tokenized": "Single Word"})
pd.concat([df1, df["Tokenized"])\
```